# not able to access a page in code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, custom-error-pages

I created a new static page in code igniter whose url is http://localhost/erostrading.in/static-page. But whenever I try to access it it redirects me to http://localhost/erostrading.in/404_override and give a 404 error page.

Header File where link is getting generated

```
<li><a href="static-page" class="<?php if(in_array($pagename, $ContactArray)){ echo "active_link"; } else { echo ""; } ?>">Static page</a></li>
```

Route File set the route to index on static page

```
//==static-page==//
$route['static-page'] = 'StaticPage/index';
```

StaticPage.php Controller file in application/controllers

```
<?php
//application/controllers/StaticPage.php

class StaticPage extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Load a view with some text
        $this->load->view('static_page');
    }
}
```

static_page.php file in application/views

```
<!-- application/views/static_page.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Static Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Static Page</h1>
    <p>This is a simple static page with some text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

tried every thing but stil the page is  not opening

Comment: it should work, using `href="/static-page"`